# Getting the last chosen image in input type FILE in edit form because user doesn't want to change the picture

Tags: php

I am having concern re this input type FILE I used for uploading an image. In an edit state, every time the user enters the edit form, the input type file for the image becomes null. Its not like every time the user edits, he/she would want to edit his/her picture, too. I am trying to apply `value="<?php echo $fuser['file'] ?>"` just like what i did with the input type TEXT, but i have learned that putting value for an input type file is just a waste. How would I get the value of the last chosen image so that when a user does not want to edit the picture, the image still remains.

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if($_SESSION["schoUsername"]) { ?>
<?php
    include('konek.php');

    $user=mysql_query("select * from tblscholar where id='$_REQUEST[edit_id]'");
    $fuser=mysql_fetch_array($user);
    if(isset($_POST['UPDATE']) && $_POST['UPDATE']=='Update')
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $schoSurname=$_POST['schoSurname'];
        $schoFirstname=$_POST['schoFirstname'];
        $schoMiddlename=$_POST['schoMiddlename'];
        $schoCourse=$_POST['schoCourse'];
        $schoSchool=$_POST['schoSchool'];
        $schoSag=$_POST['schoSag'];
        $schoPosition=$_POST['schoPosition'];
        $schoUsername=$_POST['schoUsername'];
        $schoPassword=$_POST['schoPassword'];
        $schoEmail=$_POST['schoEmail'];
        $file=$_FILES['file']['name'];

        $error=array("schoSurname"=>"","schoFirstname"=>"","schoMiddlename"=>"","schoCourse"=>"","schoSchool"=>"","schoSag"=>"","schoPosition"=>"","schoUsername"=>"","schoPassword"=>"","schoEmail"=>"","file"=>"");

        //********************schoSurname*********************
        if($schoSurname=="")
        {
            $error['schoSurname']="Lastname Is Required.";
        }
        else
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$schoSurname))
            {
                $error['schoSurname']="Lastname Can't Contain Numeric Value.";
            }
            else
            {
                $valid_lastname=$schoSurname;   
            }
        }

        //********************schoFirstname*********************
        if($schoFirstname=="")
        {
            $error['schoFirstname']="Firstname Is Required.";
        }
        else
        { 
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$schoFirstname))
            {
                $error['schoFirstname']="Firstname Can't Contain Numeric Value.";
            }
            else
            {
                $valid_firstname=$schoFirstname;    
            }
        }

        //********************schoMiddlename*********************
        if($schoMiddlename=="")
        {
            $error['schoMiddlename']="Middlename Is Required.";
        }
        else
        { 
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$schoMiddlename))
            {
                $error['schoMiddlename']="Middlename Can't Contain Numeric Value.";
            }
            else
            {
                $valid_middlename=$schoMiddlename;  
            }
        }

        //********************schoCourse*********************
        if($schoCourse=="")
        {
            $error['schoCourse']="Course Is Required.";
        }
        else
        { 
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$schoCourse))
            {
                $error['schoCourse']="Course Can't Contain Numeric Value.";
            }
            else
            {
                $valid_course=$schoCourse;  
            }
        }


        //********************schoSchool*********************
        if($schoSchool=="")
        {
            $error['schoSchool']="School Is Required.";
        }
        else
        { 
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$schoSchool))
        {
                $error['schoSchool']="School Can't Contain Numeric Value.";
        }
        else
        {
                $valid_school=$schoSchool;  
        }
        }

        //********************schoEmail*********************
        if($schoEmail=="")
        {
        $error['schoEmail']="Email Is Required.";   
        }
        else
        {
        if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $schoEmail))                                                                                                                       
            {
                $valid_email=$schoEmail;
        }
        else 
        {
                $error['schoEmail']="Invalid Email Address.";
        }
        }

        //********************file*********************
        if($file=="")
        {
        $error['file']="Image Is Required.";    
        }
        else
        {
        if($_FILES['file']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['file']['type']=='image/jpg')   
            {
            $valid_file=$file;
        }
        else
        {
            $error['file']="Image Must Be .jpg or .jpeg";   
        }
        }

        if( (strlen($valid_lastname)>0) && (strlen($valid_firstname)>0) && (strlen($valid_middlename)>0) && (strlen($valid_course)>0) && (strlen($valid_school)>0) && (strlen($valid_email)>0) && (strlen($valid_file)>0))
        {
        $sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblscholar WHERE schoEmail='$schoEmail' id!=$_REQUEST[edit_id]");
            $n=mysql_num_rows($sel);
            if($n==0)   
        {
            $path="scholarspics/";
            copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path.$file);
            $upd="update tblscholar set schoSurname='$schoSurname',schoFirstname='$schoFirstname',schoMiddlename='$schoMiddlename',schoCourse='$schoCourse',schoSchool='$schoSchool',schoSag='$schoSag',schoPosition='$schoPosition',schoUsername='$schoUsername',schoPassword='$schoPassword',schoEmail='$schoEmail',file='$file' where id=$_REQUEST[edit_id]";
            mysql_query($upd);
            echo "<script>
            alert('(Id No.$_REQUEST[edit_id]) Record Successfully Updated.');
            window.location='Dashboard.php';
            </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $error['email'] = "Same Email Already Exist";
        }
        }
    }

?><head>
<title> Edit Record </title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php include "header.php";?> </head>

<div id="divTitleHead">
<strong>EDIT SCHOLAR</strong>
</div>
    <div id = "divInsertAnnouncement">
         <div id="divInnerIA">

             <form name="f1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="70px">ID</td>
                        <td width="7px">:</td>
                        <td color="#0d192f"><b><?php echo $fuser['id']; ?></b></td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lastname</td>
                        <td>*</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="schoSurname" id="schoSurname" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoSurname']; ?>" />
                            <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoSurname"];?></span>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="schoFirstname" id="schoFirstname" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoFirstname']; ?>" />
        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoFirstname"];?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Middle Name</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="schoMiddlename" id="schoMiddlename" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoMiddlename']; ?>" />
        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoMiddlename"];?></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>School</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="schoSchool" id="schoSchool" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoSchool'];?>" />
        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoSchool"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>Course</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="schoCourse" id="schoCourse" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoCourse'];?>" />
                        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoCourse"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>SAG</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="schoSag" id="schoSag" class="box">
                            <option value="Businesslicious" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Businesslicious') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Businesslicious</option>
                            <option value="Engineering" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Engineering') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Engineering Design</option>
                            <option value="Gods_Squad" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Gods_Squad') echo "selected='selected'";?>>God's Squad</option>
                            <option value="Marketista" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Marketista') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Marketista</option>
                            <option value="MDAS" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='MDAS') echo "selected='selected'";?>>MDAS</option>
                            <option value="Professional_Warriors">Professional Warriors</option>
                            <option value="Rhetor" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Rhetor') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Rhetor</option>
                            <option value="Socialites" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Socialites') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Socialites</option>
                            <option value="Techies" <?php if($fuser['schoSag']=='Techies') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Techies</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>Position</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="schoPosition" id="schoPosition" class="box">
                        <option value="President" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='President') echo "selected='selected'";?>>President</option>
                        <option value="Vice_President_Internal" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Vice_President_Internal') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Vice President Internal</option>
                        <option value="Vice_President_External" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Vice_President_External') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Vice President External</option>
                        <option value="Secretary_General" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Secretary_General') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Secretary General</option>
                        <option value="Assistant_Secretary"<?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Assistant_Secretary') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Assistant Secretary</option>
                        <option value="Finance_Committee_Head" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Finance_Committee_Head') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Finance Committee Head</option>
                        <option value="Legal_and_Corporate_Affairs_Committee_Head" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Legal_and_Corporate_Affairs_Committee_Head') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Legal and Corporate Affairs Committee Head</option>
        <option value="Spiritual_and_Community_Services_Committee_Head" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Spiritual_and_Community_Services_Committee_Head') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Spiritual and Community Services Committee Head</option>
                        <option value="Librarian" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Librarian') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Librarian</option>
                        <option value="Member" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Member') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Member</option>
                        <option value="Leader" <?php if($fuser['schoPosition']=='Leader') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Leader</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="schoUsername" id="schoUsername" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoUsername'];?>" />
        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoUsername"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="schoPassword" id="schoPassword" class="box" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoPassword'];?>" />
        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["schoPassword"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>*</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="schoEmail" class="box" onblur="checkEmail('checkEmail.php?schoEmail='+this.value)" class="fieldsize" value="<?php echo $fuser['schoEmail']?>"/>
        <span class="err" id="checkEmail"><?php echo $error["schoEmail"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="file" /><br>
                        <img src="scholarspics/<?php echo $fuser[11]; ?>" height="150" width="150"/>
                        <span class="err"><?php echo $error["file"];?></span></td>
                </tr>                 
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn"onClick="alert('No Changes Have Been Made');window.location='viewscholars.php';" />
                    <input type="submit" name="UPDATE" value="Update" class="btn" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You can not pre-fill the value for a file input field for security reasons (and it would be the path of the file stored on your server in what you tried anyway, which the client can do nothing with). Check whether the user actually uploaded a new file or not – and act accordingly, _only_ update the file column in your database if they did so, otherwise leave it alone.

Comment: If file input is nul, do not take an action for that. So, last image will be remain same.